# How do I pass Oracle PL/SQL constants as parameters using jOOQ?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, jooq

I'm trying to convert some Oracle queries using PL/SQL to jOOQ. Most package queries, stored procedures, etc. are easy, using the code generator. However there's one feature used in several places for which I haven't found a jOOQ alternative:

```sql
begin
  MY_SCHEMA.MY_PACKAGE.MY_QUERY(some_param => MY_SCHEMA.MY_PACKAGE.SOME_CONSTANT)
  -- more code
end;
```

I can call the query just fine, but I'm not sure how to pass the `MY_SCHEMA.MY_PACKAGE.SOME_CONSTANT` value into it. The jOOQ code generator doesn't seem to generate anything for the constant (at least, I can't find anything similarly named). Do I need to enable a feature on the generator? Or do I need to query those constants? If so, how?

Comment: If it matters, I'm using jOOQ 3.15.4 and Oracle 19.

Comment: I don't know about an option because I don't think they exist in the data dictionary. If found this issue https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6504 But I don't know PLSCOPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Enabling PL/Scope for this to work

jOOQ can generate code for your package constants *if* it can find them in your `ALL_IDENTIFIERS` dictionary view. That's only the case if you enable [`PLSCOPE_SETTINGS`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/plscope-12cr2) when compiling your packages, e.g. using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET PLSCOPE_SETTINGS='IDENTIFIERS:ALL'
```

With that in place, jOOQ will generate expressions for your package constants, which you can use in routine calls, or other [procedural logic](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/procedural-statements/).

#### PL/Scope independence

What Simon Martinelli referred to in the comments is issue https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6504, which attempts to enable this code generation support even without the above PL/Scope setting turned on, because that's quite unreliable depending on your environment.

As of jOOQ 3.15, there's no solution yet that works on any Oracle environment. [But you could use testcontainers to generate your jOOQ code](https://blog.jooq.org/using-testcontainers-to-generate-jooq-code/) from a Docker image that has PL/Scope enabled.

Comment: Does the `GenerationTool` try to set `ALTER SESSION SET PLSCOPE_SETTINGS='IDENTIFIERS:ALL'` itself? If not, where can I hook into it (or the `OracleDatabase`) to set it?

Comment: @Jorn: This isn't a property of the session that *reads* the packages, but of the session that *creates* (and compiles) them, similar to `javac` compilation flags that allow for including debug information in byte code. So I don't think the jOOQ generator would be the right place to do that.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I guess I'm out of luck for this particular database, since I'm not the one generating the schema.

Comment: @Jorn: Well, if you could replicate it to a local machine (e.g. via https://testcontainers.org, and e.g. using Gerald Venzl's XE docker images: https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe), then you could re-compile the packages with that `PLSCOPE_SETTINGS` turned on, and it should work? Might be a bit excessive just for that `CONSTANT` use-case, but maybe you can otherwise improve your development? If not, you can always subclass `OracleDatabase` or `JavaGenerator` to implement your own logic, e.g. searching for constants using regexes in `ALL_SOURCE`?